# OrderBy ascending with a group by expression. Do I need it?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I'm developing an Entity Framework 4.4.0.0 Code First library with C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

Previously I had this:

```
var msgs = from message in context.Messages
            where message.TalkId == talkId &&
                (message.SentBy == userId || message.SentTo == userId)
            orderby message.DateUtcSent
            select message;
```

And now I have this:

```
var msgs = from message in context.Messages
            where message.TalkId == talkId &&
                (message.SentBy == userId || message.SentTo == userId)
            group message by message.DateUtcSent into grps
            select new
            {
                Value = grps
            };
```

Because I want to avoid repeated rows.

**Do I still need `orderby message.DateUtcSent` with this group by expression?**
**How I can add it (if I need it)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an order-by you don't have any ordering guarantees. If you need the guarantee, add the order-by. Without order-by any observed order is purely coincidental.

You can add an order-by by adding `orderby grps.Key`. Feel free to ask follow-ups in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but, where do I have to add `orderby grps.Key`? I'm very new on Linq.

Comment: After the group-by. C# behaves differently than SQL. You can add the possible LINQ clauses in any order you like. You can insert an order-by anywhere you want to create order.